# listen a power-button event in Python (no ACPI)

Tags: python, power-management

I am using a Debian machine which does not include the acpid package. Is there a way that I can reboot the machine using Python language when the power-button is pressed, without installing that (or any other) package on the machine? Currently nothing is happening when the button is pressed.

Comment: On machines sold in this millenium it is very common for powerbuttons to emit ACPI events. Are you simply missing the `acpid` or are you actually on a machine without ACPI?

Comment: ACPI is installed into /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-686/kernel/drivers/ location but I am missing the acpid package.